# python облачное хранилище mega

Tags: python, словари, облако, google-cloud

Спасибо за внимание, вообщем у меня проблема мне нужно сделать поиск файлов на mega.nz у самой библиотеки mega.py, есть функция получения всех файлов get_files(), но проблема в том что я не понимаю как достать оттуда имена каких либо файлом потому что через get_files() передается какой то массив и я не знаю как его расшифровать что бы достать имена.
Вот сама библиотека и документация: https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py

```html
from mega import Mega

mega = Mega()
m = mega.login("", "") # email, password


files = m.get_files()

print(files)
```

вот вывод что выводит print(files) с одним единственным файлом на хранилище:

{'UuBxQAAa': {'h': 'UuBxQAAa', 'p': '', 'u': 'p6xwWjBTPls', 't': 2, 'a': {'n': 'Cloud Drive'}, 'ts': 1644245207}, 'B6IXwAJS': {'h': 'B6IXwAJS', 'p': '', 'u': 'p6xwWjBTPls', 't': 3, 'a': {'n': 'Inbox'}, 'ts': 1644245207}, '06AznIyR': {'h': '06AznIyR', 'p': '', 'u': 'p6xwWjBTPls', 't': 4, 'a': {'n': 'Rubbish Bin'}, 'ts': 1644245207}, 'M3JD0CQT': {'h': 'M3JD0CQT', 'p': 'UuBxQAAa', 'u': 'p6xwWjBTPls', 't': 0, 'a': {'c': 'gG240EYUq8W3E3Uv7qM_VwT67wJi', 'n': 'hotel california.mp4'}, 'k': (1381804801, 3275684124, 2132057791, 717316428), 's': 1393295, 'fa': '27:8*3eU--YWeHEc/115:0*87PXm_lMPQk/700:1*gO51DMdCufA', 'ts': 1644620019, 'iv': (4107211365, 3532299158, 0, 0), 'meta_mac': (3520083696, 3141360663), 'key': (2794699108, 297034378, 2932123727, 2449227099, 4107211365, 3532299158, 3520083696, 3141360663)}}

**Там виден мой файл hotel_california.mp4 но как его достать для поиска и тем более, все которые я загружу в будущем, я не знаю помогите**

Comment: Не массив, а словарь со словарями, вполне типичная структура для питона

Comment: `print([file for file in files.values() if file['a']['n'] == 'hotel california.mp4'])`

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: Здравствуйте, у меня проблема можете помочь?, вообщем пытаюсь скачать себе текстовый файл c хранилище и выдает ошибку файл качает ну пустым, from mega import Mega

mega = Mega()
m = mega.login("", "") # email, password

file = m.find("hotel.txt")
m.download(file)

Comment: return self._download_file(file_handle=None,
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 745, in _download_file
    shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)
  File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 812, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\\Users\\NIGGA2~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\megapy_r0z9_pji'